# Nested loops and matrices in C++

Tags: c++, nested-loops

I have been trying to write a c++ program for doing the addition of 2 matrices and this is the code
 i have written. But i keep having the error saying "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)" Can you please help me find my error?

```
    int main()
    {
        float a[3][3],b[3][3],c[3][3];
        int l,k;

        cout<<"tell me the nr of lines in the vectors"<<endl;
        cin>>l;
        cout<<"tell me the nr of columns in the vectors"<<endl;
        cin>>k;
        for(int i=1;i<=l;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=k;j++){
                cout<<"A["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"]= ";
                cin>>a[i][j];
            }
        }
        for(int i=1;i<=l;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=k;j++){
                cout<<"B["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"]= ";
                cin>>b[i][j];
            }
        }
        for(int i=1; i<=l;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=k;i++){
                c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout<<"the sum of matrices A & B is;"<<endl;

/* i have also added this code here instead of the following loop just to see if there was a problem with the addition procedure or displayin the results;
cout<<c[i][j];   */

        for(int i=1;i<=l;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=k;j++){
                cout<<c[i][j];
            }
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @Eyup Yilmaz Array indices in C++ start from 0.

Comment: @dan should i add that as using namespace std::array<std::array<float, 3>, 3> or how?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I have tried it but nothing changed.

Comment: `0xC0000005` is access violation. Meaning your code is attempting to access memory that it does not own.

Comment: @Eyup Yilmaz also these statements          cout<<"tell me the nr of lines in the vectors"<<endl;
        cin>>l;
        cout<<"tell me the nr of columns in the vectors"<<endl;
        cin>>k; do not make sense because there is no check whether the user entered correct values.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow how exactly can i add a verification/checking procedure?

Comment: Using if () statements make sure that `k` and `l` are between 1 and 3. You could loop while either of these are outside the range.

Comment: You can test that the inputs are 1, 2 or 3, e.g. `do { std::cin >> l; } while((l < 1) || (l > 3))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your sum logic, the nested iterator variable `j` is not being incremented, it's `i`.
Which looks like:

```
for(int i=1; i<=l;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=k;i++){ /*Change i to j*/ 
                c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
            }
        }
```

So, it looks like:

```
for(int i=1; i<=l;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=k;j++){
            c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
            }
    }
```

And the whole code becomes:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        float a[3][3], b[3][3], c[3][3];
        int l, k;

        cout << "tell me the nr of lines in the vectors" << endl;
        cin >> l;
        cout << "tell me the nr of columns in the vectors" << endl;
        cin >> k;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                cout << "A[" << i << "]"
                    << "[" << j << "]= ";
                cin >> a[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                cout << "B[" << i << "]"
                    << "[" << j << "]= ";
                cin >> b[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << "the sum of matrices A & B is;" << endl;

        /* i have also added this code here instead of the following loop just to see if there was a problem with the addition procedure or displayin the results;
    cout<<c[i][j];   */

        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                cout << c[i][j];
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Final Output:

```
tell me the nr of lines in the vectors
2
tell me the nr of columns in the vectors
3
A[1][1]= 1
A[1][2]= 2
A[1][3]= 3
A[2][1]= 4
A[2][2]= 5
A[2][3]= 6
B[1][1]= 1
B[1][2]= 2
B[1][3]= 3
B[2][1]= 4
B[2][2]= 5
B[2][3]= 6
the sum of matrices A & B is;
24681012
Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### PS: Do not start indexing with 1, start with 0

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please tell me why it is important to start indexing from 0 if it works when i start by 1?

Comment: @drescherjm Just wanted to point where exactly the OP is making mistake.

Comment: ***why it is important to start indexing from 0*** Because arrays are indexed as 0 .. size-1 in `c++` using 1 .. size is Undefined Behavior and makes your whole program undefined. The result of the program is meaningless when you have UB.

Comment: The reason for indexing with 0 is that arrays can typically be indexed with pointers i.e.

`int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *ptr = arr;
`
When you write `arr[0]` it typically means `*(arr + 0)`
Unless you are in Matlab and don't want to have undefined behaviour always go for indexing with 0.

Comment: ***if it works when i start by 1?*** It does not actually. One of the worst behaviors of Undefined Behavior is when broken code (code that violates the rules of the language) seems to give you the expected result. This gives you a false sense that that the program is working correctly when the program is broken and may fail when you recompile, update your compiler, the temperature in the room changes ... [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) here you were accessing outside the bounds of the array established in the rules of the language.